# Помогите с запросом пожалуйста, поиск по первым символам в строке

Tags: java, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Суть проблемы есть столбец в базе в нем записаны строки 0004 68 0C 33 03 C2 50 A3 E9 мне необходимо искать по первым символам  0004. Есть такой запрос

```
select count(*) from last_key_activation where ActivationCode like '0%' = ?
```

Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) from last_key_activation where ActivationCode like '0004%'
```

https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp

На сколько понял по добавленному скрину, вы хотите динамически подставлять начало строки как параметр:

```
select count(*) from last_key_activation where ActivationCode like ?

...
ps.setString(1, phonenumber + "%")
```

Comment: а что будет если надо найти 0100 ?

Comment: select count(*) from last_key_activation where ActivationCode like '0100%'

Comment: это не работает

Comment: это не может не работать. добавил ссылку в ответ. проверяйте имя таблицы и имя поля

Comment: Добавил скрин, может я не верно описал проблему.

Comment: проблему вы описали не верно - добавил в ответ решение